Selenium-java freezing and crashing my computer running multiple tests concurrently since Chrome 124 update
Apologies ahead of time, this is my first question here.
After Google Chrome updated to v124 on April 16th, I could not run my XML file of 64 tests without freezing and crashing my computer.
I have JDK11 installed.  I am using IntelliJ with Maven and selenium-java 4.18.1
The tests would complete fine when I locally ran the XML of 64 tests until Chrome updated.
When I try to run them, halfway through I suddenly cannot browse websites and my mouse starts freezing. Then I cannot close any windows or even open Task Manager.  I start seeing errors in the IntelliJ console like these:
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer

and
WARNING: Failed to shutdown Driver Command Executor

The only other big warning/error I see is this, which is expected with the Chrome update, and selenium-java hasn't released a new version with CDP 124 yet:
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 124, returning the closest version; found: 122; Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 124

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
If I comment out all tests except 8-12, it can finish without failing.

When I run a few tests, and after the tests are done running, it seems there are still come Chrome processes left behind running under IntelliJ that are using 8-12% CPU each constantly.

I have figured it out.  In my Chrome options, I had been using '--no-sandbox' by default.  I removed the '--no-sandbox' option and now it runs less processes for my tests and also these do not remain behind after my Selenium does it's teardown cleanup.

The error message states, Please update to a Selenium version that supports CDP version 124. Did you do that? I see that you updated Chrome (the browser) and Java but not Selenium.
Please try update your selenium version to 4.20.0

At the time I was working on this a week ago, 4.20.0 was not released yet.
Updating it now does get rid of the warning, but not the overall problem.
